# Delete row if the cell name already exists in previous row in Excel

Tags: excel

I ran into a problem, which I cant really seem to solve in excel.
I have a huge database with 500 000+ rows of data.

The first column contains a certain name of a product and the other columns show category, website worldwide sales, etc.

As the dataset collects products from different regions and countries, A lot of them are duplicated in the dataset.

What I would like to do is if the product name in a certain row already exists then the row should be deleted.

Im thinking of a function similar or something like: If "cell with product name" can be found in the earlier rows, then delete row, if not keep row

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has the function UNIQUE that will remove duplicates based on the entire row. So, if you have 2 lines that have the same product name, but different categories or other data, it will return both lines. The below table shows using UNIQUE on the whole table, and using UNIQUE just on the product, then OFFSET to retrieve the first set of data for that product (lose information but get ONLY unique products).

```
=UNIQUE(A1:D7)

=UNIQUE(A1:A7)
=OFFSET(B$2, MATCH(J1,A2:A7,0),0,,3 <number of data columns>)
```

| A: product | B: data 1 | C: data 2 | D: data 3 |  | F: unique table product | G: data 1 | H: data 2 | I: data 3 |  | J: unique product product | K: data 1 | L: data 2 | M: data 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 8 | 9 |  | a | 5 | 8 | 9 |  | a | 5 | 8 | 9 |
| b | 7 | 4 | 3 |  | b | 7 | 4 | 3 |  | b | 5 | 8 | 9 |
| d | 9 | 7 | 2 |  | d | 9 | 7 | 2 |  | d | 5 | 8 | 9 |
| a | 5 | 8 | 9 |  | c | 2 | 2 | 3 |  | c | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| c | 2 | 2 | 3 |  | a | 3 | 8 | 9 |  |  |  |  |  |
| a | 3 | 8 | 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |