# The most fast and efficient way to clean ~100GB csv from duplicates by one column

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, dask, python-polars

I have ~100GB csv file with following columns:

```
sex;name;dob;hash
```

This files was created after some processing of another .csv file. And it can contain tuples, that's why there is this hash column. What I need is to delete duplicates from this file based on 'hash' column and save new data into output.csv.

I'm looking for both speed and efficiency. I've tried uploading to PostgreSQL using Polars, then select only unique columns:

```
    df.write_database(
        table_name=input_table,
        connection=connection_for_db,
        if_table_exists='append'
    )

    SELECT sex, name, dob
      FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT ON (hash)
              hash, sex, name, dob
          FROM input_table
      ) with_hash
```

But the uploading to DB is way too slow!
I've tried to read this .csv using Polars LazyFrame:

```
    df = pl.scan_csv(input.csv, separator=';', infer_schema_length=0,
                     ignore_errors=True, rechunk=False)
    uni_df = df.unique(subset=['hash']).drop('hash')
    uni_df.sink_csv(output.csv, separator=';', maintain_order=False)
```

But python takes too much memory as a result my PC run out of memory and the script got killed. The last thing I've tried to do was to load and clean data using Dask:

```
    ddf = dsk.read_csv(input.csv, sep=';')
    ddf = ddf.drop_duplicates(subset=['hash'])
    ddf.to_csv(output.csv, sep=';')
```

It's working but it is also taking too much system memory. So I'm really out of options here and will be very glad if someone can help me to solve this issue. As I can have bigger files in future and would like to know how to deal with them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your CSV file. Is it a complex CSV or a simple one? Maybe avoiding to use libaries or defaulting to `csv` might make the process faster.

Comment: Every approach will need a lot of either ram(scarce) or disk space (slow). You could try to reduce ram by only saving in memory the hash and a row index or file pointer position into the CSV, find the duplicates and copy the CSV without the duplicates in a second step. Other approach split the CSV into multiple files by the first digit or byte of the hash, process each subfile in memory and finally join the subfiles to a result CSV.

Comment: Have you tried just maintaining a set of seen hashes and stream reading and writing using just the csv package?

Comment: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741627/218663) has an example of what I suggest as _"A more efficient version of @IcyFlame's solution"_. If you try this and it works, you might flag this as a duplicate. I would do so now, but I'm not sure given the `dask` and `polars` tags.

Comment: Have you tried [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html)? `duckdb.sql("copy (from 'in.csv' select distinct on (hash) *) to 'out.csv'")` (install the "nightly" release from pip via `--pre` for latest speedups/fixes). Also, have you considered using parquet instead of csv?

Comment: I'm voting to close. It's either a duplicate of what @JonSG's linked or it's unanswerable because you say it's "too slow" but compared to what? Some things just take the time they take.

Comment: Please add a sample of the data, especially the hash colum.

Comment: @JonSG thank you for this link! I hope this will work for me!

Comment: @jqurious hi, I'm sorry to bother you! I've managed to rewrite my code so it works with polars lazyframe, create list of lazy dfs, then concat this list and sink_csv. It has very good performance on small dataset. But with ~5 millions rows of csv it got stuck on sinking to csv. Do you have any idea why this can happen and what can I do to make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Repzz You could try `sink_parquet` to see if that works (that could rule out if `sink_csv` is the problem). If you have a reproducible test case you may need to ask for help on Polars discord/Github.

Comment: @jqurious thank you so much! `sink_parquet` didn't work either. I'll ask for help on Polars GitHub. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the crux of the issue is that even maintaining a `set()` of hashes might not be practical as a 100g file might potentially have 25g or more of hex string hash data.

If this is the case, we can take our original 100g file and break it into chunks (temp files) based on the partial value of each row's hash. Then once we have a set of temp files, we just iteratively use them to construct the final distinct file but using only 1/16th the memory to maintain the `set()`

**Note: VERY lightly tested**

```py
import contextlib
import csv
import glob
import os

filename_in = "./my_huge_file.csv"
filename_out = "./my_huge_file.distinct.csv"
scratch_folder = "./scratch"

## ----------------------
## Ensure a clean slate
## ----------------------
if os.path.exists(scratch_folder):
    raise FileExistsError(f"The folder {scratch_folder} already exists.")
os.mkdir(scratch_folder)
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## Split our monster file into chunks based on the last character in "hash"
## ----------------------
writers = {}
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    for row in csv.reader(stack.enter_context(open(filename_in, "r")), delimiter=";"):
        key = row[3][-1] # the last character of the hash

        ## ----------------------
        ## Get or create the writer for this key
        ## ----------------------
        writer = writers.setdefault(
            key,
            csv.writer(stack.enter_context(open(f"{scratch_folder}/{key}.csv", "w", newline="")), delimiter=";")
        )
        ## ----------------------

        writer.writerow(row)
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## Now we apply our "seen" test to each of the scratch files
## in turn.
## ----------------------
with open(filename_out, "w", newline="") as file_out:
    writer = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=";")
    for filename in glob.glob(f"{scratch_folder}/*.csv"):
        seen_hashes = set()
        with open(filename, "r") as file_in:
            for row in csv.reader(file_in, delimiter=";"):
                key = row[3]
                if key not in seen_hashes:
                    seen_hashes.add(key)
                    writer.writerow(row)
        os.remove(filename)
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## clean up the scratch folder
## ----------------------
os.rmdir(scratch_folder)
## ----------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! that's really a great solution, I'll try this out as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=UNIQUE` in Excel or the like (**if the file opens at all in Excel**), see this example: [Delete row if the cell name already exists in previous row in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432818/delete-row-if-the-cell-name-already-exists-in-previous-row-in-excel)

This would empty duplicate cells and then you can remove all rows where a given cell is empty, see https://superuser.com/questions/474530/excel-delete-row-if-cell-in-certain-column-is-blank.

If this is not feasible for you, then you can do inserts into the database, but I would not do it with distinct values. Instead, I would create a `unique` index in the database table on your hash and do an insert which does nothing when the constraint is violated. Example:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (hash, sex, name, dob) 
SELECT 'myhash', 'M', 'John', '2020-01-01 0:00:0'
FROM input_table
ON CONFLICT (field_one) DO NOTHING;
```

If the hash is computed based on these three fields, then you probably do not need a hash, but a `unique(sex, name, dob)` in your target database.

Comment: Can you open a 100 gig file in excel? If you can cool but I was under the impression/delusion that might not be possible.

Comment: @JonSG if you have enough horsepower then you can. Since we write answers both for the present and the future, I'm being agnostic about technical limitations regarding RAM memory.

Comment: True enough and I did not downvote. I'm just assuming that there is some excel row limit that might make this impossible even with lots of ram.

Comment: @JonSG points are well taken, independently of who the down-voter is. I'm happy to improve this answer with or without down-votes and any criticism is more than welcome as long as it is constructive. I have edited my answer to reflect your concern regarding the limitations. The second part of my answer was more about running SQL insert commands profiting from the unique index. Also, we actually can open this in Excel even if we pass the limitation; but in that case we might need to break the file into smaller packets. But, if we break up the file, then the first approach in the answer will

Comment: ... no longer work. But, luckily the second part of the answer will work.